# Installed from ISO

Tags: 12.10, boot

I installed ubuntu 12.10 from an iso disk. It partitioned 6gig and proceeded to install in conjuction with a prexisting version of win7. Install was successful however I can not get it to boot Ubuntu. PLease help.

Regards,
JT

Comment: 6GB is quite small, is this a wubi install where Ubuntu gets installed in a virtual drive inside the Windows file system?

Comment: No this was done through ubuntu? How much space should io allocate for Ubuntu?

Comment: I can certainly partition the drive myself, renaming it and allocating more space.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, but a new install will need just under 4Gb of hard drive.  You will need extra space for maintenance such as installing updates, log files, temp files etc, plus any other programs you want to install. 12GB is workable if you don't install any large database programs, CAD, games etc.  Some games can be one or two GB. 20Gb is generally more than enough for most people excluding data.

Comment: JT, 6Gb should be more than enough for a fresh install of Ubuntu.. 
i have it installed on a 4Gb thumbdrive without issues.. 

When you say you "can not get it to boot ubuntu", do you mean you never see a Grub screen at boot time?

Comment: Correct... Just boots to win7 with no questions asked or other opportunities

Comment: Ubuntu was installed last and GRUB does not appear anywhere

Answer (score 0):

When you re-install do it manually (select "something else" when prompted) and make sure that it is installing the grub bootloader on the correct drive.  See if the installation finishes correctly and give you a bootable Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please Answer The Following Questions to narrow down the Problem.

- Was Ubuntu installed Last?
- Does GRUB Appear or the system Boots into Windows Directly?

I Personally Don't think That it is a space issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Problem here is that either you didn't install the GRUB Boot loader, or You installed it in a separate Hard drive.

The Best Thing to do is:

Boot From the Ubuntu ISO into Live Environment and follow this Tutorial

[Restore Grub Tutorial](http://fosswire.com/post/2009/05/restoring-overwritten-grub/)

Comment: @Andrew...Im Stuck again...